# Convert the string to date

Tags: apex, formula-field

I have a text field which holds date in below format

> ```
> 1/15/2020 11:43 AM
> 1/9/2020 11:43 AM
> ```

Now, what I need to do is, create a SOQL query that will filter this field.
One approach can be, create a formula field that will convert the string to date. But in that case, what will the formula.

How can I do that?

N.B: I can not change the field type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing this is inefficient--you will need to query the *entire table* to filter for records. This will result in slow reports for large objects and is not scalable. Create a secondary field (date-time) and convert the string to a date using a trigger or Process Builder, then you can filter on that efficiently.